# Problems on Trafodion Installing with Python Installer

Tags: ssh

I am new to trafodion and I am try to install traofdion on CDH 5.7 with python installer according to apache trafodion site.

```
[root@node1 python-installer]# ./db_install.py
**********************************
Trafodion Installation ToolKit
**********************************
Enter HDP/CDH web manager URL:port, (full URL, if no http/https prefix, default prefix is http://): http://10.1.1.10:7180
Enter HDP/CDH web manager user name [admin]:
Enter HDP/CDH web manager user password:
Confirm Enter HDP/CDH web manager user password:

***[ERROR]: Host [node1]: Failed to connect using ssh. Be sure:
1. Remote host's name and IP is configured correctly in /etc/hosts.
2. Remote host's sshd service is running.
3. Passwordless SSH is set if not using 'enable-pwd' option.
4. 'sshpass' tool is installed and ssh password is correct if using 'enable-pwd' option.
```

Also check these errors
1./etc/hosts and hostname is corrected

```
[root@node1 python-installer]# hostname
node1.trafodion.local
[root@node1 python-installer]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.1.1.10 node1.trafodion.local node1
10.1.1.11 node2.trafodion.local node2
10.1.1.12 node3.trafodion.local node3
10.1.1.13 node4.trafodion.local node4
```

2. sshd service is running

```
[root@node1 python-installer]# service sshd status
openssh-daemon (pid  3480) is running...
```

3. each two nodes could passwordless ssh

4.sshpass is not installed

```
[root@node1 python-installer]# sshpass
-bash: sshpass: command not found
```

Thank you for any help.

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to ssh to node1 .. node4 manually using `root` user, it would be easier to detect any ssh login issues. If manually ssh could work, the installer should work too.

Comment: I did check again and found that I missed to add rsa key to the node1 itself. Now it is working. Thank you so much.